# How to remove relations from MongoDB models

Tags: mongodb, nosql, relation

Is there any possible way to list `relations` between models in `Mongodb` and remove or edit them?

**update Schema:**
company:

```
{
  "company": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "tel": "string",
  "id": "string"
}
```

product:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "qty": 0,
  "exp": "string",
  "id": "string"
}
```

update 2:

```
"relations": {
    "products": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "product",
      "foreignKey": "comp_id"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you be more concrete? How does your database Schema look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've created wrong relation `hasmany` and `belongs to` relation by loopback then I removed relations from loopback project but still getting error that `Relation "products" is not defined for company model` . company and product are without relation.

Comment: Can you paste your Schemata with some dummy values? Don’t do it as comment, rather update your question. It’s hard to help you when you describe your problem with one sentence.

Comment: @AlexP. I have updated some  information.

Comment: So where is your connection here, between your two collections?

Comment: I have removed manually from Schema, but when I want to insert into any of them gives error for relation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not utterly sure what you are trying to accomplish. But I have an advice for you on how to design your Schemata and add your `foreign keys`

If I was you, I would design my **company** collection like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a291fd838f4fb1fc057bbbc"), // _id is automatically generated if you don't provide any
    "name" : "ABC", 
    "tel" : "1234567"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29208838f4fb1fc057bbbf"), 
    "name" : "DEF", 
    "tel" : "5556667"
}
```

And this is how I would design my **product** collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a29211838f4fb1fc057bbc4"), 
    "name" : "ProductA", 
    "qty" : NumberInt(1), 
    "exp" : "exp1", 
    "companyIds" : [
        ObjectId("5a291fd838f4fb1fc057bbbc"), // the foreign keys of the each company
        ObjectId("5a29208838f4fb1fc057bbbf")
    ]
}
```

This way it would be easier to delete and or update your collections.